Forcefield parameterization techniques
Suppose I have a novel synthetic protein. I want to find the classical forcefields that accurately models the dynamics and thermodynamics of the protein. How do I do that?

Please limit your posts to include only 1 question.

There are many FFs that are available at your disposal, such as CHARMM, AMBER and OPLS. These FFs will have residues that form the part of the protein that you are interested in, and can be directly transferred for your purposes (unless you have some synthetic amino acids, even then these FFs would have molecules which closely match them).
Instead, if you decide to go with parameterizing the amino acids, please be advised that it is a long and complicated process (usually worthwhile for a PhD, especially if you parameterize a family of molecules) undertaken by a group of people.
The reminder of this answer is strictly for CHARMM, but you should be able to find references for other FFs easily.
If you have access to CHARMM FF, you must check in files named "top_all36_prot.top" and "par_all36_prot.prm" to see if they have the amino acids that you have in your protein of interest. If you find them, you are done. Else, try and identify residues that closely match the ones that you have, and then create a new residue based on them (this step is called transfer of parameters). You then test these parameters, and refine them. You would be able to find literature on how is this optimization done quite easily.
